# Unable to show data in ChartJS in ASPX, 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, chart.js

Actually I'm new in ASP and i'm trying to show in ChartJS some data from mySql database, for a test I've made a simple table with 3 row's that has as year 2011 and as month February, I would show the quantità for that year and month.

The issue is when i'm running the website I get the 500 (Internal Server Error) but the problem is if i put a break-point in the method which in the asmx file the site even doesn't reach it.

Here is my webservice.asmx code:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class webservice
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService
    Dim SQLConnect As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myConnectionString").ConnectionString

    <WebMethod()>
    Public Function getTrafficSourceData(ByVal gData As List(Of String)) As List(Of trafficSourceData)
        Dim t As List(Of trafficSourceData) = New List(Of trafficSourceData)()
        Dim arrColor As String() = New String() {"#231F20", "#FFC200", "#F44937", "#16F27E", "#FC9775", "#5A69A6"}

        Using cn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(SQLConnect)
            Dim myQuery As String = "select * from statistica where anno =@year and mese=@month"
            Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = myQuery
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", gData(0))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month", gData(1))
            cmd.Connection = cn
            cn.Open()
            Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            If dr.HasRows Then
                Dim counter As Integer = 0

                While dr.Read()
                    Dim tsData As trafficSourceData = New trafficSourceData()
                    tsData.value = dr("quantita").ToString()
                    tsData.label = dr("nomeprodotto").ToString()
                    tsData.color = arrColor(counter)
                    t.Add(tsData)
                    counter += 1
                End While
            End If
        End Using

        Return t
    End Function
Public Class trafficSourceData
    Public Property label As String
    Public Property value As String
    Public Property color As String
    Public Property hightlight As String
End Class
```

End Class

While here is the JQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var gData = [];
        gData[0] = "2011";
        gData[1] = "FEBBRAIO";

        var jsonData = JSON.stringify({
            gData: gData
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "webservice.asmx/getTrafficSourceData",
            data: jsonData,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess_,
            error: OnErrorCall_
        });

        function OnSuccess_(response) {
            var aData = response.d;
            var arr = [];
            $.each(aData, function (inx, val) {
                var obj = {};
                obj.color = val.color;
                obj.value = val.value;
                obj.label = val.label;
                arr.push(obj);
            });
            var ctx = $("#chartMensile").get(0).getContext("2d");
            var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(arr);
        }

    function OnErrorCall_(response) {
        alert("ERRORE!");
    }

});
```

Comment: HTTP 500 status indicates there is unhandled exception occurred when AJAX call passed to webmethod. Try using debug mode to capture the exception details.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto so i should put a breakpoint on $.ajax? because i'm trying to do it but that's the result https://imgur.com/GoPn1uv

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto after focusing each field of ajax it gives in type : type undefined, in url undefined etc.